# Vega Multi Series Line Chart - Use Dashed Line for One Series

Tags: visualization, vega-lite, vega

I have a multi series line chart, with custom colors for the lines based on a domain (category) which is field `c` in my data

[image]

I'm looking to have the `Alpha` category line (in this example) displayed in a dashed style - but so far I've only seen examples where all the lines are dashed

My current Vega spec/config is as below

- link to runnable online version via the [vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgBMABh1L4NMlm16lUOQDMjaUEyRQA1mQBObBrLVoQmF0lkQOEgucLKYiiDENHDKtiAQvmyOcN6+-oHBoeEAvkrBNCiovgxwuSBqSJiFoLJICCnoVUyCKUrESIIlEGgA2qAAHmj6IACeQ+beAIKCODAouQNoAIxKY6gAzBPo07PzCouoWqvLWyA7cyALIIOow2srIFDeAEJwVZf71yej2qev71cbkcfrc-m95gBdMrIFyOOKYEY4BogYSyVogGhhOAuHBsQSVZEIORsTBydG4zHhVCWDoQUpKUIWNSYshxG6gBFI7wARwY-kwdEqNFIEWscEEXnQgzKaw5iORvP5goFIqUYol3jGZQsgjYLji6sljwinORsjYCExHQi0A6DVAagtSExvTOMwuSn+KAhSj8sjIDR6IBcZCYAApdPoAASRhQxvQASgiIfDWgAHHGxCsowBOHNJqHZItAA)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "config": {
    "background": "transparent",
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
    "aria": true
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "table",
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 0, "c": "Alpha"},
      {"x": 1, "y": 3, "c": "Alpha"},
      {"x": 2, "y": 1, "c": "Alpha"},
      {"x": 0, "y": 1, "c": "Beta"},
      {"x": 1, "y": 2, "c": "Beta"},
      {"x": 2, "y": 0, "c": "Beta"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "line", "interpolate": "monotone", "point": false},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "field": "x"
    },
    "y": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "field": "y"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "c",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["Alpha", "Beta"],
        "range": ["rgb(200, 200, 200)", "rgb(28, 51, 99)"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide a scale. Enjoy.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "config": {
    "background": "transparent",
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
    "aria": true
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "table",
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": 0, "c": "Alpha"},
      {"x": 1, "y": 3, "c": "Alpha"},
      {"x": 2, "y": 1, "c": "Alpha"},
      {"x": 0, "y": 1, "c": "Beta"},
      {"x": 1, "y": 2, "c": "Beta"},
      {"x": 2, "y": 0, "c": "Beta"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "line", "interpolate": "monotone", "point": false},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "x"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "y"},
    "color": {
      "field": "c",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "domain": ["Alpha", "Beta"],
        "range": ["rgb(200, 200, 200)", "rgb(28, 51, 99)"]
      }
    },
    "strokeDash": {
      "field": "c",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"domain": ["Alpha", "Beta"], "range": [0, 10]}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice one - similar pattern to the `color` - this is great, thanks